# MySQL Insert data to table using column number not name

Tags: mysql, insert

Do I have to know the name of the column so to be able to insert data ? because I need to insert data using column number (first column is 1...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using this :

```
insert into my_table (column1, column2)
    values (value1, value2)
```

Just use that :

```
insert into my_table values (value1, value2)
```

i.e. don't specify the list of columns.

Of course, this will only work if you pass data for the columns **in the order they are defined in the table**, though.

Comment: +1 Also, this will work ONLY if you insert data for all columns, not some of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a table like (for example) :

```
CREATE TABLE  test (
   id INT(10),
   field1 VARCHAR(16),
   field2 TINYINT(1)
);
```

you can execute the query

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'field1 value', 0);
```

The insert values **must be in the same order as the declared columns**. And as Galz mentioned it, you **must set all fields**, even the nullable or the auto incrementing ones. In fact, for the latter, you have to pass a `null` value.

For example, if `id` were to be a primary key set to "`auto_increment`", this query

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (null, 'foo', 1);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Would return

```
+----+--------------+--------+
| id | field1       | field2 |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | field1 value |      0 |
|  2 | foo          |      1 |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

---

On another subject, if you don't know beforehand what is the order of the fields, you can execute this query :

```
show columns from <table name>;
```

which, in this case would return

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field1 | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field2 | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Thus telling you that `id` is the first field, `field1` is the second, and `field2` is third.